# Laravel many to many relationship getting role shared by two user models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

the question is simple if I have a many to many relationship between users and roles and  two users have a shared role between them is there an eloquent way to get that shared role or do I have to call each of their roles and use two foreach loops  to match their records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following query should do the trick:

```
$userId1 = 123; // just some assumption...
$userId2 = 234; // can of course be a user object as well

$roles = Role::query()
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($userId1) {
        $query->where('users.id', $userId1);
    })
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($userId2) {
        $query->where('users.id', $userId2);
    })
    ->get();
```

In words, that query basically means: *Give me all roles which are associated to the user with id `$userId1` **as well as** a user with id `$userId2`*.

Comment: it returned an sql error:   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: I updated the answer. It seems that using a `table.column` combination within the `where()` clauses is necessary. So simply replace `where('id', $userId)` with `where('users.id', $userId)`.